# Проверка if/else при пустых данных в первом поле

Tags: java, android

Есть `java`:

```
    TextView fdBreakfastHint = listItems.findViewById(R.id.fdBreakfastHint);
    TextView fdDinnerHint = listItems.findViewById(R.id.fdDinnerHint);
    TextView fdSupperHint = listItems.findViewById(R.id.fdSupperHint);
    TextView fdSnackHint = listItems.findViewById(R.id.fdSnackHint);


    if (fdBreakfast.getText().equals("")) 
        return listItemView;
    else 
       fdBreakfastHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (fdDinner.getText().equals("")) 
       return listItemView;
    else 
       fdDinnerHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (fdSupper.getText().equals("")) 
       return listItemView;
    else 
       fdSupperHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (fdSnack.getText().equals("")) 
       return listItemView;
    else 
       fdSnackHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Проблема в том, что проверка идет сверху вниз. То есть, если, например, поле `fdBreakfast` заполнено, то поле `fdBreakfastHint` становится видимым. Далее, все идет **по порядку**, то есть сверху вниз.

Но если заполнено только первое поле, то условие прерывается, и нижние соответствующие поля, даже если, например, `fdSnack` заполнен, не становятся видимыми.

Наверное, нужен цикл, но не пойму, как его составить.

**Как сделать так, чтобы проверка, в случае отсутствия данных в первом поле, не останавливалась?**

Comment: Не пробовали использовать  editText.addTextChangedListener? Мне кажется он лучше подойдет в вашем случае. И никаких циклов не надо.

Comment: Выполнение любого метода заканчивается на ``return``. Поэтому, как только выполнен первый ретурн, то все, что ниже него, не выполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за ответы, решил немного иначе, но при помощи @Artem Konovalov

Для начала поменял свойства на TextView (убрал INVISIBLE):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fdBreakfastHint"
    android:text="Завтрак"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fdDinnerHint"
    android:text="Обед"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fdSupperHint"
    android:text="Ужин"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fdSnackHint"
    android:text="Перекусы"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

И далее java:

```
if (fdBreakfast.getText().equals(""))
            fdBreakfastHint.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (fdDinner.getText().equals(""))
            fdDinnerHint.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (fdSupper.getText().equals(""))
            fdSupperHint.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (fdSnack.getText().equals(""))
            fdSnackHint.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Напишите так:

```
if (!fdBreakfast.getText().equals("")) 
   fdBreakfastHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if (!fdDinner.getText().equals(""));
   fdDinnerHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if (!fdSupper.getText().equals(""));
   fdSupperHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if (!fdSnack.getText().equals(""));
   fdSnackHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

return listItemView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо больше информации о контексте, когда вызывается этот метод в целом.
Всё дело в **return** listItemView;

Вам необходимо вынести действие которое должно происходить с контролом в случае успешной проверки и не успешной.

Например вот так:

```
if (fdBreakfast.getText().equals("")) SetNoValid(fdBreakfast);
    else SetValid(fdBreakfast);
```